# 2sxc change the default "edit" form

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

Another n00bish question.

What is the fastest / easiest way to change the default toolbar - "edit" record/row form?

I give simple names to content fields like "dname" and "cname" (easier to call latter and prevents special chars errors) but I need the edit button in toolbar to call a different form where the full name of the fields is shown (like "Default çãç123##$$% name" and "Common /*-~ºç name") and sometimes other info.

What is the best way to do this? Can't find any info on this on documentation...

Best regards,
João

Comment: I really don't understand the question, sorry :)
Especially since each field can have multi-language labels, so they are easy to customize...

Comment: Sorry. Sometimes we mix 100 problems and everything seems quite clear. My question now: how do I replace the default "edit record" form? Any tutorial on example on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "just plug in another form" feature, but you can create your own form, and read/write using REST APIs.

This form would then by default not be part of the toolbar - so you would have own links which activate the form.

It could then be added to the toolbar (there's an api for that), but that would be the last step.

Comment: Creating the links would be easy. The API not so much. Opening the mobious form example seems like pure C# nightmare, completely out of reach for me, unless there is a very basic example I can follow or tweak. I will try reading the tutorials available in you help / apps sections. Thanks.